# Get string from adb shell and use string as value in setting next command

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I am trying to automate some batch scripting that I want to:

1. Get the WLAN mac address of an android device using `adb shell ip
   address show wlan0`
2. Set the android device's name to the last three octets of the mac
   address so it is easy to identify the device using `adb shell
   settings put global device_name TAB3-<last three octets>`

The mac address is always on the second line of the output of the following:

```
adb shell ip address show wlan0
8: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 3000
    link/ether 14:9f:3c:ca:dd:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.29.14.16/23 brd 172.29.15.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::169f:3cff:feca:ddce/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I would like to get that last three octets, e.g. `ca:dd:ce` and then set the device name using those last three octets but without the colons appended onto the string `TAB3-`, e.g.:

`adb shell settings put global device_name TAB3-caddce`

I have been digging into bash scripting but I am really not getting how to actually read the last three octets of the mac address.  The OUI `14:9f:3c` should stay the same all the time.

This is how far I've gotten to actually reading the second line of the output and storing it in a variable but unsure how to proceed past this?

```
echo on

for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('adb shell ip address show wlan0') do (
    if not defined second_line set "second_line=%%a"
)

echo %second_line%
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out, maybe not the best method but happy to hear other suggestions!  Below is the code.

```
::Read MAC Address from second line of adb shell ip address show wlan0
echo Reading MAC Address ...
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('adb shell ip address show wlan0') do (
    if not defined second_line set "second_line=%%a"
)
:: Parse out the OUI and everything before it (assumes OUI is 14:9f:3c i.e. Samsung)
echo %second_line%
for /f "delims=c tokens=1*" %%a in ("%second_line%") do set "second_line_parsed=%%b"
::echo %second_line_parsed%
:: Parse out everything after the NIC designation in the MAC addr (e.g. the brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff part)
for /f "delims=@" %%a in ("%second_line_parsed:brd=@%") do set "second_line_parsed_mac=%%a"
::echo %second_line_parsed_mac%
:: Remove the extra colons in the MAC addr
set "second_line_parsed_mac_cleaned=%second_line_parsed_mac::=%"
echo Found %second_line_parsed_mac_cleaned% as last three octets in WLAN0 NIC MAC
set "device=Tab3-"
echo Setting device name to %device%%second_line_parsed_mac_cleaned%
adb shell settings put global device_name %device%%second_line_parsed_mac_cleaned%
echo Done
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to use the string on the device side anyway - there is no reason to do the processing on the PC host side:

```
adb shell "settings put global device_name TAB3-$(ip -o addr show dev wlan0 | grep -o 'ether [^ ]*' | cut -c16- | tr -d :)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the OUI is constant, you could just use that as a search pattern:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "OUI=14:9f:3c:" & Set "MAC="
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In (
    'adb shell ip address show wlan0^|FindStr "\<%OUI%"') Do Set "MAC=%%A"
If Not Defined MAC Exit /B
Call Set "NIC=%%MAC:*%OUI%=%%"
Set "NIC=%NIC:~,2%%NIC:~3,2%%NIC:~6,2%"
Rem Your commands below
Echo %NIC%
Pause
```